# Swift: Sending network request one after another

Tags: ios, swift

I want to send requests one after the other. Wait for the response from the first to send the second.

Currently I use this:

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
            let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

            dispatchGroup.enter()
            self.requestOne { _ in
                dispatchGroup.leave()
            }
            dispatchGroup.wait()


            dispatchGroup.enter()
            self.requestTwo { _ in
                dispatchGroup.leave()
            }
            dispatchGroup.wait()


            dispatchGroup.enter()
            self.requestTree { _, url in
                user.profileImage = url?.absoluteString
                dispatchGroup.leave()
            }
            dispatchGroup.wait()


            self.requestFour { error in
                completion(error)
            }
        }
```

It works very well but I wanted to know if there is a way to make this cleaner, swiftier without using

```
dispatchGroup.enter()
dispatchGroup.leave()
dispatchGroup.wait()
```

Even a pattern to wrap logic in a class

Comment: I wouldn't recommend hand rolling something like this. Use a better abstraction, like a Promise (such as from PromiseKit) or observable (such as from Combine or RxSwift)

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50026983/how-can-you-use-dispatch-groups-to-wait-to-call-multiple-functions-that-depend-o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## A simple network layer utilizing Combine

This answer is heavily influenced by [this post](https://www.vadimbulavin.com/modern-networking-in-swift-5-with-urlsession-combine-framework-and-codable/). I removed unnecessary code where possible and added code where needed to compose a working playground.

#### Api unrelated layer parts

```
import Foundation
import Combine

struct Agent {

    func run<T: Decodable>(_ request: URLRequest, _ decoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder()) -> AnyPublisher<T, Error> {
        return URLSession.shared
            .dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
            .tryMap { result -> T in
                return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: result.data)
            }
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

#### Api related layer parts

```
enum GithubAPI {
    static let agent = Agent()
    static let base = URL(string: "https://api.github.com")!
}

extension GithubAPI {

    static func repos(username: String) -> AnyPublisher<[Repository], Error> {
        let request = URLRequest(url: base.appendingPathComponent("users/\(username)/repos"))
        return agent.run(request)
    }

    struct Repository: Codable {
        let node_id: String
        let name: String
    }

    static func issues(repo: String, owner: String) -> AnyPublisher<[Issue], Error> {
        let request = URLRequest(url: base.appendingPathComponent("repos/\(owner)/\(repo)/issues"))
        return agent.run(request)
    }

    struct Issue: Codable {
        let url: URL
    }

}
```

#### Actual clean and swifty code you are looking for

Note that issue request depends on repo request. Actual requests are triggered with sink call.

```
let user = "Alamofire"
let repos = GithubAPI.repos(username: user)
let firstRepo = repos.compactMap { $0.first }
let issues = firstRepo.flatMap { repo in
    GithubAPI.issues(repo: repo.name, owner: user)
}
let token = issues.sink(receiveCompletion: { (_) in }) { (issues) in
    print(issues)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calling dispatchGroup.leave() in the requests completion, why don't you just call the next request there:

```
self.requestOne() { [weak self] _ in
   guard let `self` = self else { return }
   self.requestTwo() { [weak self] _ in
      guard ..
      self.requestThree...
   }
}
```

Or as suggested in a comment, use a framework like RxSwift or Combine

EDIT:
When some requests will be called on others not, based on different conditions, you could check the condition in your `requestXX` method. If condition isn't met, just call completion and return.

```
func requestTwoIfNeeded(paramsToCheckCondition, completion: ...) {
   guard conditionMet else {
      completion(state)
      return
   }
   self.requestTwo(completion)
}

func sequentialRequests(completion: ...) {
   self.requestOne() { [weak self] _ in
      guard let `self` = self else { return }
      self.requestTwoIfNeeded(conditionalParams) { [weak self] _ in
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Because certain requests will be surrounded by a condition so not all requests will be sent. So if one is not sent it will break the rest

Comment: Then maybe rewrite the request methods to check the condition.